# How to generate auto incremented id for each table separately using SQL Server and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to have separate auto incremented id generator for each of my entities.

The target database is a SQL Server database, and I am using Hibernate 5.2.4.Final. Also I am generating the tables from code.

I have an abstract `BaseEntity` and other child entities like below, and thus, I am aiming for `TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) 
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.XXX)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tags")
public class Tag extends BaseEntity {
}
```

Below are the different scenarios that I have faced so far:

- setting `XXX` to `AUTO`: Creates a `hibernate_sequence` table in database, which I assume, will not provide separate id sequence for separate table.
- setting `XXX` to `SEQUENCE`: Same as above. Referred [this](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-identity-sequence), while doing it.
- setting `XXX` to `TABLE`: Creates a `hibernate_sequences` table, which can provide separate id sequence for separate table. However, I have found out that this is quite expensive (same reference as above), and also not my preferred strategy.
- setting `XXX` to `TABLE`: Does not work for `TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

What I actually want to use is the native identity column of SQL Server. However, using the [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) is also an option, but I am not sure how to create and use one for each table from hibernate. Please suggest how either one of these two can be achieved.

**Update** on the answer by Khalil M. I tried it in 2 possible ways:

1. applying on `BaseEntity` ->  does not create a separate sequence for each table, and rather creates a `ID_SEQNCE`, which queried before saving every new entity. So, I am not sure how this is any different than using `GenerationType.TABLE`.
2. applying it on each individual entity class -> while saving, the generator creates duplicate id.

Answer (score 0):

for creating a sequence use this

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ID_SEQNCE",allocationSize=1)
```

Edit:
You have to make it by yourself because what you are asking is not supported in **Table per class**

> the id has to be shared across several tables. Consequently, when
>   using this strategy, you should not use AUTO nor IDENTITY.

for more [info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1191)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it didn't work as expected. Please check the updated question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY

A short example is below

```
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)

private Long id;
```

The GenerationType.IDENTITY is the easiest to use but not the best one from a performance point of view. It relies on an auto-incremented database column and lets the database generate a new value with each insert operation. From a database point of view, this is very efficient because the auto-increment columns are highly optimized, and it doesn’t require any additional statements.